# Quickest way to create DataTable from query?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, datatable

What is the code with the smallest number of lines that will generate a `DataTable` from this SQL query?

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Table1] 
WHERE ([Date] BETWEEN @Date1 AND @Date2) AND 
      ([Field1] IS NULL OR [Field2] IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use [SqlDataAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to fill a DataTable.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
using (SqlConnection yourConnection = new SqlConnection("connectionstring"))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("....your sql statement", yourConnection))
    {
        using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
            da.Fill(dt);
        }
    }
}
```

Use [using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) block with your `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataAdapter` since they implement `IDisposable` interface. Also use [Parameterized](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6tdby40.aspx) query

Comment: Wouldn't you want to include the "using" statement with the SqlCommand and SqlDataAdapter as well, since they also implement IDisposable?

Comment: @NightShovel, that is correct. I should have used the using blocks.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
using(SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
     dt.Load(reader);
}
```

Comment: I would say this is the answer :)

Comment: -1, DataReader is not suitable if have to populate the dataset. It is useful in the cases where you need to utilize the data while reading it.

Answer (score 1):

SqlDataAdaptor and FillSchema

It will create your table on the fly

Applied On a DataSet

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.aspx

Applied On a DataTable

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/152bda9x.aspx